# How to Sort List<> with property of a user defined object?

Tags: c#

I have a `List<OrderTime>` with OrderTime as shown below

```
public class OrderTime
    {
        public string OrderId { get; set; }
        public DateTime StarTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to sort this list in ascending order of `DateTime StarTime`. I can do it with bubble sorting, but want to know is there any c# built in methods

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use `LINQ`

```
List<OrderTime> _orders = new List<OrderTime>();
// _orders.Add(...);
var _result = _orders.OrderBy(x  => x.StarTime);
```

Comment: Exactly, you can also do this, `_orders = _orders.OrderBy(x => x.StarTime).Cast<OrderTime>().ToList();`

Comment: But why do I need to do it explicitly? is there a chance to lost data?

Comment: because the records are not sorted the way you want. remember it's a list, so the first record you have inserted is the first element on the list unless you have specified an index to where you want to insert. Lost of data? -- No. You are only reording the elements on the list.

Comment: Keep in mind that by doing `.OrderBy` the original list (`_orders`) isn't effected.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett what do you mean? `var _result = _orders.OrderBy(x  => x.StarTime);` or this one `_orders = _orders.OrderBy(x => x.StarTime).Cast<OrderTime>().ToList();`?

Comment: @JW: Sorry, didn't see your comment. I was referring to the answer as is.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett I understood that. But I didn't get the difference between the list type  got after reordering.

Comment: @JW hOW TO SORT DESCENDING???  I'm not familiar with this lamda functions. Please help

Comment: use [OrderByDescending](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderbydescending.aspx) so in your query,`_orders.OrderByDescending(x  => x.StarTime);`

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use

```
lst.Sort((x, y) => x.StarTime.CompareTo(y.StarTime));
```

Remember that using lst.OrderBy().ToList() will create a new instance of List<>, probably hurting performance.

Doc: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx